# "Exception caught by widgets library" in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

My screen on the app was shown blank on this layout and when i debug the code, I'm getting this error in flutter app. Now, i don't have any idea how to get it solved "

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following TypeErrorImpl was thrown building GetBuilder<OrderController>(dirty, state: GetBuilderState<OrderController>#8f677):
Unexpected null value.
```

"

here is the code:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool isLoggedIn = Get.find<AuthController>().isLoggedIn();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: CustomAppBar(title: 'checkout'.tr),
      endDrawer: const MenuDrawer(), endDrawerEnableOpenDragGesture: false,
      body: isLoggedIn ? GetBuilder<LocationController>(builder: (locationController) {
        return GetBuilder<RestaurantController>(builder: (restController) {
          bool todayClosed = false;
          bool tomorrowClosed = false;

          if(restController.restaurant != null) {
            todayClosed = restController.isRestaurantClosed(true, restController.restaurant!.active!, restController.restaurant!.schedules);
            tomorrowClosed = restController.isRestaurantClosed(false, restController.restaurant!.active!, restController.restaurant!.schedules);
            _taxPercent = restController.restaurant!.tax;
          }
          return GetBuilder<CouponController>(builder: (couponController) {
            return GetBuilder<OrderController>(builder: (orderController) {
              bool showTips = orderController.orderType != 'take_away' && Get.find<SplashController>().configModel!.dmTipsStatus == 1 && !orderController.subscriptionOrder;
              double deliveryCharge = -1;
              double charge = -1;
              double? maxCodOrderAmount;
              if(restController.restaurant != null && orderController.distance != null && orderController.distance != -1 ) {

                deliveryCharge = CheckoutHelper.getDeliveryCharge(restController: restController, orderController: orderController, returnDeliveryCharge: true);
                charge = CheckoutHelper.getDeliveryCharge(restController: restController, orderController: orderController, returnDeliveryCharge: false);
                maxCodOrderAmount = CheckoutHelper.getDeliveryCharge(restController: restController, orderController: orderController, returnMaxCodOrderAmount: true);

              }
```

I've tried to search solution but no luck!

Comment: Have you checked whether this  orderController is null or not ?

Comment: Firstly you are using twice the getbuilder(Not required as per the code), and secondly you are not returning any widget in second getbuilder